# Connecting Amazon RDS for Oracle

Tags: vba, oracle, excel, oracle11g, rds

I am working on a project to connect and import data from *Amazon RDS for Oracle* through VBA Excel Macro. I tried various online resources but couldn't find anything relevant.

I tried using the following connection string,

```
dbconn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>;DBQ=<AWS_RDS_ENDPOINT>"
```

I have also setup the oracle client in my system,but the connection is not working.

Can someone please guide me in writing the correct connection string and setting up the required environment.

Comment: *the connection is not working* - what error are you getting, specifically?

Comment: The firewall on the Amazon server/AWS instance would need to allow the connection through (SQL*Net, port 1521?). You won local network's firewall might need tweak to allow this traffic through too.

Comment: A good resource for connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/search/  ...  Also have you checked here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html

Comment: @TenG Should I configure that in AWS security group?

Comment: @peppygeeks I cannot remember exactly where, but certainly when we set up our AWS Oracle server when open up the sqlnet port using the online portal on AWS.